# QListWidget проверка на выделение

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Как правильно организовать проверку на выделение какого-либо элемента QListWidget. В пример прилагаю мой QListWidget с таймерами - элементами списка.

[image: Мой QListWidget]

Моя тщетная попытка.

```
for(int i = 0; i < timers.size(); i++){
     if(listW->item(i)->isSelected())
         tmp = listW->item(i)->text(); 
} // По идее, если какой-то элемент выделен, он записывается в переменную tmp
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems

Comment: + https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemSelectionChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете итерировать выбранные элементы или индексы:

```
QStringList selected;
QList<int> selectedRows;
// Можно получить текст из выделенных элементов
foreach (QListWidgetItem *wi, ui->listWidget->selectedItems())
    selected.append(wi->text());
qDebug()<<selected;

// или получить и текст и номер строки
selected.clear();
foreach (QModelIndex mi, ui->listWidget->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes()){
    selected.append(mi.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
    selectedRows.append(mi.row());
}
qDebug()<<selected<<selectedRows;
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь)